# How to change the roundness and size of a brush in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, configuration

When I try to use a calligraphy brush the roundness and the size doesn't change to another option.

1. I go to `Brushes Library Menu` → `New Brush` and select the `Calligraphy Brushes`
2. The Calligraphy brush menu pops up with three main options: Angle, Roundness and Size.

It's not allowing me to change these options, what am I doing wrong?

**Why can't I change the brush options in Adobe Illustrator?**

Comment: Create any circle and drag and drop it to brush panel

Comment: @Ilan that won't create a calligraphic brush.

Comment: @Scott Ya, I didnt read the Q well

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new Calligraphic Brush you need to type the Angle and Roundness, you have a slider only for the Diameter that you can drag and these **CAN** be edited even if you have them **Fixed** and not **Random**.

You need to change to Random only if you want to add a **Variation** to the brush.

> **What is variation?**
>
> *helpx.adobe.com* : Enter a value in the Variation box to specify the range within which
> the brush characteristic can vary. For example, when the Diameter
> value is 15 and the Variation value is 5, the diameter can be 10, or
> 20, or any value in between.

[image]

*PS: If this doesn't help, please create a print-screen of how your Calligraphic Brush Options looks like.*

Comment: OMG, I just now saw that this question was asked 12 months ago :|My answer came 11 months and 28 days too late :))))

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the "variation" options on the right, you need to first change the **Fixed** drop down to something else, like **Random**.

Be aware many of the dropdown options are not available without a tablet.